# RecyclerView de Imagens com Problema ao carregar imagens==null

Tags: android, imagem, android-recyclerview

Olá, pessoal.

Estou fazendo um RecyclerView com um TextView e um ImageView que é carregada do banco.
O problema é quando esta imagem é nula. A Recycler View vai bem até uma certa parte e depois ela começa a colocar imagens que não existem onde há imagem==null.

Tentei com Picasso e com o Fresco e o erro é o mesmo.
E não são todas as vezes que acontece isso, só as vezes, aleatoriamente.
As Views que tem imagem estão perfeitas.

A eu estou fazendo um aleatório, para que os dados sejam exibidos aleatoriamente.
Alguém pode me ajudar?
Estou usando o seguinte:

```
     Random gerador = new Random();
    position = gerador.nextInt(listadicas.size());

    final ParseObject dican = listadicas.get(position);


    holder.tituloDica.setText(dican.getString("nome"));


        if (dican.getParseFile("foto") != null) {
            holder.fotodica.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            holder.fotodica.setImageURI(dican.getParseFile("foto").getUrl());

        }
```

Obrigada

Comment: tenta deixar o imageview com "imgView.setVisibility(View.GONE);" quando não houver imagens.

Comment: Olá, Anderson. Já tentei, mas acontece mesmo assim .

Comment: Tem como colar seu recyclerview todo aqui?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if (dican.getParseFile("foto") != null) {       
    holder.fotodica.setImageURI(dican.getParseFile("foto").getUrl());
}else{
    holder.fotodica.setImageURI("www.url.com/imagem.png");     
}
```

Comment: Deu certo! Melhor que isto, só dois disso!

Comment: Obrigada! Vocês são d+!

Answer (score 0):

```
if (dican.getParseFile("foto") != null) {
    holder.fotodica.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);  
    holder.fotodica.setImageURI(dican.getParseFile("foto").getUrl());
}else{
    holder.fotodica.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);          
}
```